# Is there a way to add a placeholder to a text field in KendoUI Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I tried the following to add the placeholder attribute to the input field using the following code,

```
    dataSource: {
        ...
        schema: {
            data: "storeEmployeeData",
            total: "storeEmployeeDataCount",
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: true },
                    FirstName: { type: "string", nullable: true, editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                    MiddleName: { type: "string", nullable: true, editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                    LastName: { type: "string", nullable: true, editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                    **Email: { type: "string", nullable: true, editable: true, placeholder: "(optional)", validation: { email: true, required: false } }
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    }
```

Also tried the following,

```
    columns: [
        { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", type: "string", width: "150px" }, 
        { field: "MiddleName", title: "Middle Name", type: "string", width: "150px" }, 
        { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", type: "string", width: "150px" }, 
        { field: "Email", title: "Email", type: "string", width: "250px", sortable: false, placeholder: "(optional)" }, 
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "200px" }
    ],
```

None of them yielded the result I was looking for i.e., having placeholder attribute `placeholder="(optional)"` added to the input field.

This is part of HTML5, if this feature already exists in Kendo UI Grid is it also compatible with IE 7 and IE 8 ?

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `placeholder` option in the Kendo UI Model documentation; therefore, it is not supported directly. Reference: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model#configuration-Example. Maybe you meant to use `defaultValue`?

Alternatively, you could use the `attributes` option for the Kendo UI Grid configuration. Reference: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.attributes.

The `placeholder` attribute is only supported in IE 10 and above.

**Update:** (due to comments)

To give you an example, in order to add the `placeholder` attribute to the input element, you could use the `editor` option on the column.

```
columns: [
  { field: "Email", title: "Email", width: 250, sortable: false, 
    editor: function (container, options) {
     var input = $("<input/>");
     input.attr("name", options.field);
     input.attr("placeholder", "(optional)");
     input.appendTo(container);
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Brett,

    <td placeholder="optional" role="gridcell" data-container-for="Email"><input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="Email" data-type="email" data-bind="value:Email"></td>

It is adding placeholder to td tag instead of input tag after adding  attributes: { "placeholder": "optional" } to columns

Comment: Ah, yes, that's right. You'd then have to do something similar to this: [http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.editor](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.editor)

Comment: Awesome, removed attributes and used editor instead thanks Brett!

Comment: I didn't get how you finally did it? can you please give some more info?

Comment: Is there any way that I could add a JS function for the editor using the grid MVC helper ?

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a place holder for when there are no records then,

```
   <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      columns: [
        { field: "name" },
        { field: "age" }
      ],
      noRecords: true,
      dataSource: []
    });
    </script>
```

or

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  pageable: true,
  noRecords: {
    template: "No data available on current page. Current page is: #=this.dataSource.page()#"
  },
  dataSource: {
    data: [{name: "John", age: 29}],
    page: 2,
    pageSize: 10
  }
});
</script>
```