# How to set placeHolder in knockout-kendo multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, kendo-ui

How to set placeHolder (optionCaption in the select) in knockout-kendo multiselect

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="kendoMultiSelect: { data: doc, value: selecteddoc}"></select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you already know about optionsCaption in the classic Knockout way. 
Kendo-ui doesn't provide a placeholder apparently.

What you can try is to add an extra first value, and hide it on open.
`$dropdownElement.getKendoDropDownList().list.find("li.item").first().hide();`

```
// Classic knockout way just in case
<select data-bind="options: optionsArray, optionsCaption: 'My Caption placeholder ... ', selectedOptions: SelectedOptionsArray" size="5" multiple="true" multiple></select>
```

Otherwise you can always refer to this. 
[Is there a way to add a placeholder to a text field in KendoUI Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450382/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-placeholder-to-a-text-field-in-kendoui-grid)

Comment: It is a multiselect and not a DropDownList